# How to mock object?

Tags: java

How to mock object for testing if the class you're testing is abstract? you can't instantiate from it ?

Comment: Why are you testing an abstract class?  Surely for testing purposes, you want to check a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocking is creating a mock implementation of an interface or abstract class, and rarely of concrete classes. You can make these mocks at runtime using a mocking framework:

- [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/)
- [mockito](http://mockito.org/)
- [JMockIt](https://jmockit.dev.java.net/)

Comment: Let me just add that it's possible to mock abstract classes using additionnal code. As an example, jMock uses cglib (http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html) to mock abstract ones.

Comment: You say your favorite is JMock, I have used it .. concerning jmock .. does this mean that jmock creates a instance of mock object for you myObject = context.mock(MyObject.class); ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test the common implementation of your abstract class, then you should create a dummy concrete implementation in you test subsystem and just unit test the common methods of that class.

If, on the other hand, you need to pass around a reference to your abstract class, then, as Bozho has suggested, you should use a mocking framework. My favorite is [JMock](http://jmock.org).

Answer (score 1):

As Paddy mentions, you really want to test a concrete class.

But, if you want to test functionality provided by an abstract class, the common method for doing so is to create an `abstract` `TestCase` with an `abstract` method for providing the concrete class and then test the common functionality within your `AbstractWhateverTestCase`.

See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbstractTestCases for some examples.

Comment: Could you please show an example, how to deal with an abstract type that has dozen of abstract methods? In this case you 'AbstractWhateverTestCase' should provide implementation for all of them? Do you think this is a good idea?